# NIST ECC Curves without pairings

Tags: elliptic-curves, pairings, nist, standards, elliptic-curve-generation

NIST [FIPS.186-4](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.186-4.pdf#page=99) has standardized 5 ECC curves on field $\mathbb{F}_p$ (P-192, P-224, P-256, P-384, P-521) and 10 elliptic curves on binary fields. I need to use ECC curves without pairings for my scheme.

I am not sure which of these curves have pairings, and which of them don't.

Comment: these curves are intentionally standardized to make the use of pairings impractical.

Comment: So, doesn't NIST have any standards for curves with pairings? What curves are used for pairing-based cryptography then?

Comment: No there are no standards just yet. You can read this paper about pairings-friendly elliptic curves: https://eprint.iacr.org/2006/372.pdf